# sending attachment with mail via command line

Tags: linux, email, command-line, attachment

Im trying to send a mail with attachment over command line. For that purpose I was trying 'mail' command. Sendmail is also available on the server. All solutions I found so far are not working. I'm not admin on the server and mutt is not installed.
I tried so far:

```
mail -a "Test Body" info@test.org < test.txt
```

Sends an Email with Test Body as content and the content of test.txt, instead of test.txt as attachment.
I also tried some more variants of that, but it's always sending the content of the file as text inside the mail instead of an attachment.

It also seems like my mail version don't use '-a' as option for attachemnt:

```
mail: option requires an argument -- 'a'
usage: mail [-dEIinv] [-a header] [-b bcc-addr] [-c cc-addr] [-s subject] to-addr ...
       mail [-dEIiNnv] -f [name]
       mail [-dEIiNnv] [-u user]
```

Im using Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) and bsd-mailx 8.1.2-0.20141216cvs-2

Comment: Could you name you Linux distribution and package providing `mail` command?  `mail` command can be provided by quite different packages.

Comment: Distribution: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) , package: bsd-mailx 8.1.2-0.20141216cvs-2

Answer (score -1):

As i know there is no direct option to send mail with attachment. You can use mutt for this.
For example

```
echo "body part" | mutt -a "/filepath/file.to.attach" -s "subject" to@address.com
```

Comment: Unfortunately mutt is not available on the server. I can only use mail and sendmail

Comment: If you have rights of modified on server. Please attach mutt on server. Its provides more flexible and easy way to send mail.